# Move encrypted data from one database to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption, sql-insert, always-encrypted

I am facing an issue with encrypted data in SQL Server. I have one database (`db1`) instance that has a table with 3 encrypted columns. I have created a master column encryption key and a column encryption key and then I encrypted specific columns.

Now I have created another database instance (`db2`) and what I want is to insert select from one database to another and insert the data to my new table at db2 that has the same table schema and also the columns are encrypted.

I am getting the following error:

> operand type clash: nvarchar(max) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256',column_encryption_key_name = 'db1_CEK',column encryption_key_database_name = 'db1' is incompatible with nvarchar(max) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256',column_encryption_key_name = 'db2_CEK',column encryption_key_database_name = 'db2'

The following is the query that I am trying to run. Please bear in mind that both tables have the same schema:

```
INSERT INTO db2.Test_Table
    SELECT * FROM db1.Test_Table
```

Comment: Perhaps you will find a solution in this doc -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-migrate-using-import-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: When i alter my user with the following ALLOW_ENCRYPTED_VALUE_MODIFICATIONS = ON. The SQL server gives an error . It does not recognize the ALLOW_ENCRYPTED_VALUE_MODIFICATIONS

Comment: An update for the above i manage to alter my user for ALLOW_ENCRYPTED_VALUE_MODIFICATIONS and also added to my connection 'Column Encryption Setting = Enabled' but still i get the same error.